# High ASYNC_NETWORK_IO when user locks computer with Excel open

Tags: performance, excel, waits

I have a user who gets in at 8AM and leaves at 6PM every day, and every day I see the same strange pattern in SolarWinds DPA.

It seems that Excel is refreshing the Query Table when the user locks their screen.  My questions are:

1. Is there any way to stop Excel from doing that?  I can't be the only DBA who has fought such problems.
2. Is there any way I can reproduce the problem on my machine?
3. Help finding Google keywords to search for a known issue... I've tried unsuccessfully

[image: High Async Network IO from Excel]

*UPDATE*

It occurred to me there could be other factors at play here, so here goes:

1. The file is on a Network-Attached Storage Drive shared among a work group.
2. I looked into various Network Interface Card powersaving feature issues that could be causing Excel to think the file handle is lost (???)
3. "Refresh data when opening the file" is checked under Connection Properties
4. This may be occurring on a Virtual Machine.

I have found one other user with a similar problem: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bcc35121-1575-4a7f-b82f-1c20f6fed58d/process-blocked-by-asyncnetworkio-status-blocks-other-queries?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: Wow, interesting. You're positive it isn't actually doing any work overnight (macros or something)? Can you convince the user to close the spreadsheet when they leave? If not, I'd be tempted to just manually kill their spid at 6pm ("oops, not sure what happened"), then (if they complain) ask them to manually refresh when they come in in the morning. That assumes Excel won't retry on its own, which it just might, depending on workbook settings. Is this a spreadsheet you have a copy of? Or can get a copy of? Changing data connection settings might fix it.

Comment: "Wow, interesting" - my thoughts exactly. The user typically is good about closing down for a day, because they don't want to look at stale data the next day (implications costing him millions of dollars if making decisions on wrong data...).  I'm trying to find a more permanent solution. The other half of the problem is it's a direct query on a DB table... I am thinking if I put it in a sproc and intermediately dump to a temp table and return that, the lock will go away.

Comment: You can put your database in a single user with rollback immediate and then put in in multi user on a sceduled base, for example, at 7 PM for sure

Comment: The only downtime window is Saturdays

Comment: I have a new clue: The machines these calls come from are actually VMs.

Comment: Is it actually causing a problem? normally that wait type indicates that SQL has finished processing everything and is just waiting for the client to read all the results. See: https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/async_network_io/. If it's not actually causing any problems then I'd be inclined to just ignore it

Comment: @Greg Yes.  It causes a problem because there is nothing that forces the query to spool to a workingspace/tempdb area, such as an order by clause. The problem goes away if the database engine is forced to cache the results somewhere prior to returning them.  The problem is triggered b/c queries may start returning rows without having cached them somewhere first. Joshua R. Stern  on MSDN independently confirms this. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bcc35121-1575-4a7f-b82f-1c20f6fed58d/process-blocked-by-asyncnetworkio-status-blocks-other-queries?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: @JohnZabroski - what problem is it actually causing? Is it just that you're seeing this wait type? Is it blocking some other process? If it's just youre seeing a lot of waits, work out how to make your tool ignore it because it's making no difference to your server.

Comment: @Greg I have seen it cause blocking chains. I was using SolarWinds Database Performance Analyzer. See this comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/179585/high-async-network-io-when-user-locks-computer-with-excel-open?noredirect=1#comment438517_181886

Comment: Happened again today; trying to nail down exactly exactly how this happens. I noticed one of the queries was fairly innocent, but used a three-part name: SELECT s1.ID, 
   s1.Fieldcontainingnvarchar50, 
   s2.SecondFieldcontainingnvarchar50, 
   s2.ID
FROM MyDb.dbo.Table1 s1
JOIN MyDb.dbo.Table2 s2
ON s1.StrategyID=s2.StrategyID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` can cause database contention issues if the results being sent to the client never spool anywhere (e.g., via an `ORDER BY` clause forcing a sort in `tempdb`).

If this issue is happening with Excel, then the problem is likely due to an Excel Database Connection refreshing on the background thread and the user simultaneously locking their computer during the background refresh.  When the background thread is complete, the computer is locked.  The issue is that in Win32, a locked computer means the user session object is not available.  When the user session object is not available, there is nowhere for the background thread to return results to, and it just hangs, waiting for Excel.exe to read the results.  Because the results never spool anywhere, the `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` lock causes a *livelock* on any previously acquired locks.  In itself, `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` is harmless.  It's the *lock chain* that is doing the damage.

To sum it up, this problem can happen under the following two conditions:

1. ASYNC_NETWORK_IO is present due to a slow reader (in my case, the slow reader is *livelocked* due to Win32 user session object unavailable)
2. The results are never spooled to some intermediary object, implicitly (e.g. `ORDER BY` triggering a sort in `tempdb` on underlying table, because the data is too big to sort completely in memory) or explicitly (`INSERT` results into a `tempdb` table, do `SELECT` on the tempdb table, which releases the livelock).

Two options:

1. If you don't have control over the client's slowness?

a. Write the query results to a temp table. Return the temp table to the user.

b. Also, don't forget to SET NOCOUNT ON at the top of the stored procedure, to avoid roundtrip delays due to DONE_IN_PROC TDS messages being sent to the client.

2. If you do have control over the client's slowness?

a. Check if the NIC is misconfigured or if the client is using a VM and the VM's NIC is miconfigured. See: https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/2k7jn5/after_2_years_i_have_finally_solved_my_slow/

b. Measure using Perfmon. Microsoft uses a heuristic of 10 for PerfMon Network Output Queue Length. See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997365(v=exchg.80).aspx

c. Add Query BeforeRefresh and AfterRefresh event handlers to instrument logging clues in the Worksheet to determine what the user is doing. In particular, see "XL2000: How to Use the Query BeforeRefresh and AfterRefresh Events": https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213187/xl2000-how-to-use-the-query-beforerefresh-and-afterrefresh-events

d. Write an Excel add-in that caches their SQL calls.

*UPDATE 1/19/2018*

I'm still dealing with high ASYNC_NETWORK_IO issues with Excel users.  I believe I have found more potential causes of this, but these are just theories at this point:

1. If you have multiple tables in the same spreadsheet, and the last table to the right has more rows than the tables to the left, this seems to cause Excel to "blink" a lot.  Correspondingly, in SolarWinds Database Performance Analyzer, queries on this spreadsheet that return the most rows and columns also have the highest ASYNC_NETWORK_IO problems. (Next steps for me are to reproduce this issue, but I'm not sure it's worth my time as I persuaded one user that they didn't need that huge result set at all for now.)
2. I found a comment on Experts Exchange ( https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/25049176/Slow-queries-excuted-throug-network-ASYNC-NETWORK-IO.html ) where someone said 5,000 row results or higher are notorious for causing problems.  This appears to actually be a recommendation raised internally by Microsoft Dynamics NAV application, which is notorious for causing SQL Server instability due to high ASYNC_NETWORK_IO waits.  The error message the application raises is, "The number of records in the table exceeds the maximum number of 5000. Set a filter to decrease the number of records in the table. Exporting too many records at once can affect system performance."  But this is just a guess.
3. For SSIS Excel Destination tasks, if the user does not have permission to write to Temporary Internet Files folder, then it might just hang: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23523954/1040437  (Again, just a theory as I use this to try to collate all possible theories into one place.)

Comment: I ran into a real world issue where I saw, using Solarwinds Database Performance Analyzer, a blocking chain with an ASYNC_NETWORK_IO at the head of the chain, all due to Excel.